# Django web app embedding maps

Tags: python, django, google-maps, gis

I am working on an web project about display maps on a web page but I have zero experience in GIS related work, so I have some problem with how to draw the map.

The basic function of our page is to recognize the locations in the text input by the user, and then show the place in the map. We decide to use Django as the back end because it has a Geodjango component and we need Python's text analysis libraries.

However when I get to learn the map drawing part, I am confused with those APIs:

Can we use google maps api alone or I also have to use openlayers? I know openlayers provides the interface and google has the map data, what are the overlap? 
Do I need to store the map data in a file or database to use openlayers?
I also find that Arcgis has the javascript api but I wonder whether it provides the data.
What do I need to draw our own map?

Forgive the potentially ignorant question, I really lack relavant knowledge.

Can someone explain to me the relation between these APIs and what solution(resource) best suits our web app for us new hand in GIS work?..

Answer (score 0):

I know that there are tons of implementation related to this, but I'm just going to share what I have done.

You would first get the Lon & Lat of the location(this can be saved in whatever ways you like), then pass it to the template in your context:

```
context['gmap_coords'] = "%+f,%+f" % (lat, lon)
```

Then in your template, add an `iframe` to be the holder of the map, roughly like this:

```
<p><iframe width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe></p>
```

Then I created a javascript that fills the `iframe`:

```
$(function() {
    var cords = '{{ gmap_coords }}';                                                                                                                                  
    var url = '//maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=' + coords + '&aq=&ie=UTF8&z=14&output=embed';                            
    $('iframe').attr('src', url);                                                                                                               
});
```

Comment: Suppose I have another context defining number of people in the city. Can it be displayed on the map as well?

Comment: Sorry I don't know enough about that.